# Arduino Yun Python Script

Tags: python, linux, arduino

I'm running a Python script on OPENWRT linux that runs on Arduino Yun.

I'm doing so using the `runShellCommand()` function.

all is good but the script that I'm trying to run should open a txt file and write something to it. However, it doesn't.

It's printing what it should to the screen and i can catch is with the arduino sketch but it wont write data to the .txt file. It wont create it at all.

I'm trying to create the file at the full path: `("/root/data.txt")`.

The Python script works on regular linux client /windows platform.

Comment: Do you have write access (test with `echo Moshe >> /root/data.txt`)?

Comment: you should share the relevant parts of the code, otherwise we cannot help much

Comment: Hey there.. i have write access .. "echo 1 > /root/test.txt " worked perfect the python code works perfect on any platform what parts of the code should i share?

Comment: void runCurl() {
network
  Process p; 
 p.runShellCommand("python /root/hello.py 1");  
  flag=1;
  while (p.available()>0) {
    char c = p.read();
      if (flag){
      Serial.println("fff");
      Serial.print(c);
      if (c=='E') delaytime=60000;
    else delaytime=1000;
    if (c=='1')
      digitalWrite(pin,HIGH);
    else digitalWrite(pin,LOW);
    flag=0;
    }
  }

  // Ensure the last bit of data is sent.
  Serial.flush();
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well.. Sorry for the trouble ..
i forgot to type open("/root/database.txt") in the python code..
Sorry for the hassle... i'm using   many "open()" function, and i missed one of them
Thank a lot!
Cheers